# How do I save/load an object? I've done a lot of searching and can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: android

I've been searching for an answer for a very long time and I know this has been answered, but none of the "correct" answers have worked for me.

In my MainActivity I do:

```
SaveData save = SaveData.load(getApplicationContext());
```

and then I pull values out of it.

In SaveData I have:

```
public void save(Context context)
{
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("savedata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(this);
        os.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static SaveData load(Context context)
{
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("savedata");
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        SaveData save = (SaveData) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return save;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Every time I launch the app it crashes immediately (null pointer - obviously the file isn't being loaded properly). I have no clue what's wrong with my code and I've tried at least half a dozen different "correct" answers. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: I think I've serialized everything properly. SaveData implements Serializable and has these variable types: Class1, int, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, int. Class1 implements Serializable and has these variable types: ArrayList[Class2], ArrayList[Class2]. Class2 implements Serializable and has these variable types: String, double, double, double, String, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ArrayList[Class3]. Class3 implement Serializable and has these variables: String, double, double, double, String, String, Uri, File.

I don't know much about serialization, so it would make sense that I messed up that part. Maybe Uri and File aren't serializable?

I don't know much about saving/loading in an Android application aside from what I've read online over the last few days. In my head it was as simple as "I have this Object, I am going to throw it into a file in the phone, when I start the app again later I'll grab that file and pull the Object out, simple." Clearly it's not that simple, but I'm not sure what part I've got wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a solution:

My save/load system seemed to be working previously, then I added some additional features and it stopped working. After Abdullah Tellioglu brought up the idea that the problem might be with my serialization I did a quick Google search and realized that Uri is not serializable, so instead of saving the Uri with my Object I saved the File and used Uri.fromFile(fileVariable) wherever I need the Uri.

After fixing that problem I simply took this:

```
SaveData save = SaveData.load(getApplicationContext());
//Pull out variables
```

and changed it to this:

```
SaveData save = SaveData.load(getApplicationContext());
if (save != null)
//Pull out variables
```

so there's no problems if it's the first run and a save file doesn't exist yet.

Now everything works. It looks like the code for saving and loading was correct, but I had errors in other places.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1-Did your class implemented as serializable ? 
2-You don't need external storage permission since you are writing objects into the internal.